# How to break redirect loop

Tags: php, redirect

How can I break a redirect loop?

When submitting the form and sending data to DB by POST method I try to empty the fields by redirecting to the empty page.

redirect.php

```
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'redirect.php';
header("Location: https://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;
```

and redirect back to the form page

```
<?php 
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 't54646.php';
header("Location: https://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;
?>
```

But instead of a single redirect initiated by F5 it gets stuck in an endless loop of redirects.

How to stop this uncontrolled loop and make it initiated only by F5?

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
  $data = array(
    'id_bld' => $val[0],
    -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -
    'id_manager' => $val[34]
  );

  $elem = $_POST;
  foreach($elem as $key => $value) {}
  unset($elem['update']);

  $res = pg_update($dbconn, 'test.tb_54646', $elem, $data);
  if ($res) {
    echo "Updated";
  } else {
    echo "Not updated";
  }
}
```

Comment: Which one is your form handler? and post the part where you handle the POST data

Comment: Good, now the first code, is it in the same page as the form handling code? and what's the purpose from the redirect, you are trying to prevent form re-submission when the user refreshes the page right?

Comment: Also, I didn't get the `F5` part? and what Javascript? please re-phrase your question so that it is clear and comprehensible.

Comment: Are you making sure to check that the POST exists before redirecting? So that it only redirect's when the form is submitted and not every time the page loads.

Comment: @Mehdi Bounya ... Yes, I try to prevent form resubmission when page is reloaded  
F5 is just reload the page

Comment: @Danny... I try with different position, as at the top PHP part, as well at the bottom, as a last lines before close... result the same, non-stop loop... I even can't load this form initially, it starts lopping immediatelly and finally stops at redirect.php

Comment: Your header redirect should be only within: if (isset($_POST['update'])) {...} After the redirect that POST value will no longer exists and it will not trigger the redirect again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well then all you have to do is

```
if ($res) {
    // Only redirect when the action is successfull
    $host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
    $extra = 't54646.php';
    header("Location: https://$host$uri/$extra");
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Not updated";
}
```